# Resolving deadlock caused by parallel triggers in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-deadlocks

My friend asked me this question and I was not able to resolve it.

Consider a scenario where I have two triggers on `table1`.
Both are BEFORE INSERT triggers.
Both the triggers try to update `row 1` of `table2`.
When the INSERT query is run on `table1`, both the triggers try to update the same row of `table2` and a deadlock is caused.
This is a simplified issue.
In actual case there are around 50 triggers and some other reasons because of which we cannot use COMMIT in any of the triggers.

Now please help me resolving the above issue.

- Is there something by which I can sequence the triggers.
- Is it possible to utilize savepoints in any way to resolve this issue.
- Or any way by which I need to create a temporary table and do something with it.

Please explain if any solutions are feasible.

Answer (score 4):

Is this a real situation, or a hypothetical one? As far as I know you can only commit in a trigger with an autonomous transaction, which would explain the deadlocks because otherwise you are running the trigger code within the same transaction, and it can't deadlock itself.

Anyway, with 11.2 you control the firing order of triggers with the FOLLOWING clause: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#CJADJGIF

Triggers make application support very difficult, by the way, and often indicate a need to cope with a denormalised design that is also a problem. To be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers on the same table are executed successively in non-specified order (in fact, ordered by their object_id).
Performing commit inside trigger is bad idea.
You can use global temporary table (on commit delete rows) or package variables to store temporary data.